# order and limit with ActiveRecord sum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this ActiveRecord sum:

```
@websites = current_user.records.sum(:minutes, :group =>'website', :conditions => "website IS NOT NULL")
```

I would like to limit it to the 10 highest minute sums.  Could someone let me know the syntax for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `:order` by the summed column and then `:limit` it to 10 rows like this:

```
@websites = current_user.records.sum(:minutes,
    :group => 'website',
    :conditions => 'website IS NOT NULL',
    :order => 'SUM(minutes) DESC',
    :limit => 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `:limit`, like so:

```
current_user.records.sum(:minutes, :group => '', :conditions => '', :limit => num)
```

Comment: This won't work. This will just return the first 10 rows, but without the request order of descending sort *by* the summed column.

Comment: How about adding an :order then?